# Pipeline using S3 object key regex pattern

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Would it be possible to tell CodePipeline, which is using S3 as a source stage, to load into the pipeline all items starting with a specific pattern?
[image: S3 source stage pipeline]

In my example, I have some code behind that uploads the zip formatted as:
`code_2022-02-17.zip`
Onto a S3 bucket (bucket-specific) with a "folder"
`folder/`

Many thanks.